# How to execute a file compiled using arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, toolchain

I've written a hello world program in C on a Linux machine. The compilation was done using a toolchain `arm-none-eabi-gcc` (that I will later use for cross compilation). But I would like to test the execution of this application on the same machine before advancing any further. However, when the executable is created after the compilation, I try to execute using `./hello` but I receive the error

```
bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file
```

How do I execute then an executable that was compiled with the aformentioned toolchain?

Comment: I thought the .bin or .hex file produced by arm-none-eabi-gcc was only used for embedded microcontrollers. It has instructions that only an embedded system such as an ARM-based design would understand. If you wanted to make an executable for Linux you can just use gcc to compile the program, see "man gcc".

Comment: On what platform are you planing to install your binary? The only way to test it is to run it via a emulator. Android had an emulator if you need.

Comment: I am going to run my binary on a FOX G20 V board with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. I've already built and compiled a u-boot that will allow me (hopefully) to load my application on the board, although, up 'till now, I haven't been able to do so. And how do I run it via an emulator?

Comment: If you want an emulator, lookup how to install `qemu` on your system and how to configure it for your target.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the executable to the machine which runs the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler and execute it .
Or in the emulators .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've copied the executable in the same folder that runs the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler but I still get the same error. I'm guessing to run the executable is not by "./", am I right?

Comment: Based on the question, I believe the machine which runs the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler is actually cross-compiling the code, therefore executing it on this machine won't work.

Comment: @Khaelid Yes it's for cross compiling maybe that's why it won't execute. However, I'm also having difficulty executing the application on my target board

Comment: I was saying you  to copy the executable on the target board and run it ,not on the machine where you are cross compiling it. what problem are you facing while running on target board ?

Comment: @Praveen I get a segmentation fault when I simply copy the executable on the board.

Comment: @JohnSmith so I think you are able to executable the program ,but you are getting segmentation fault am I right ? . If so check whether the libraries which you use in the program is available in the target board .

Comment: @Praveen Yes that is correct. The libraries are available because when I load the same hello world C program compiled using `gcc` instead of `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, it executes fine.

Comment: @JohnSmith you executed the executable compiled using gcc on the target board or on your local machine ?

Comment: @Praveen Using gcc, I executed the executable on the board by loading it with scp. But when I do the same for the one compiled with arm-none-eabi-gcc, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @JohnSmith may you can try debug with gdb if available on the board . And for your FOX Board G20 I see that tutorials are available online http://www.acmesystems.it/tutorials. May be you can try these .